# No result using BITMAP

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2012

Here's a code snippet:

```
 Dim BMf As Bitmap
 BMf = New Bitmap(PicBox.Width, PicBox.Height)
 Call FourierPlot(PlotHeight, PlotWidth, RPMArray, CoefArray, Count, 2, BMf)
 Me.PicBox.Image = BMf
 BMf.Dispose()
```

within the subroutine is code such as:

```
 Dim myGraphics As Graphics = Graphics.FromImage(BMf)
 Dim myPen As New Pen(colr)
 ....
 myGraphics.DrawLine(myPen, lastx, lasty, temp1, temp2)
 ....
 myPen.Dispose()
 myGraphics.Dispose()
```

The displayed PicBox consists of a boundary rectangle with lines draw from opposing corners (what I presume is an "error image.)

Any suggestions (hopefully VERY simple ones) as to what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: You got that Dispose() call backwards.  You should dispose the *old* image, not the new one.  So use `If Me.PicBox.Image IsNot Nothing Then Me.PicBox.Image.Dispose()` before you assign the Image property.

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't call `BMf.Dispose()`, because the image is going to be used by the picture box.

Update:

OK, small update because this seems to be confusing to the OP and others.

When you say `Me.PicBox.Image = BMf` you set a reference to the bitmap. Both `BMf` and `PicBox.Image` now point to the same object. Thus, you should not dispose it, because then it can't be used anymore. Again - this is not a copy, this is same object.

And about leaks. Removing this line does not cause any memory or other leaks. .NET is managing this for you. As soon as the bitmap will not be needed (which means nobody has a reference to it = your picture box will load another image), it will be unneeded and disposed at the next run of the garbage collector. This is automatic.

You might want to disposed it manually if you really need to care about resource, for example if you would invoked your code and create new bitmaps often, many times. But in this case you probably would be better off forcing garbage collector to run in places, where you can cause some delay to the user. You can do this like this:

```
GC.Collect()
```

Comment: So what *should* he do? Your answer is incomplete.

Comment: He should remove this line, this is rather obvious?

Comment: "Pointing" out to me the behavior of the pointers straightened me out.  Again, thanks for your help.